# Vue not reacting to a change as it should - only reacts after another action performed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, javascript-objects

I'm trying to programatically toggle a class on a vuetify card.

I am toggling it based on a value on the user that is in a for loop.

I have this code which tells the card to apply a class if member.toggle is true. A users background card should turn orange, but it doesn't.

[image: This is an image]

When a user is clicked, it adds toggle:true to the user object.

[image: This is an image]

After I click on the user, I check the vue console in chrome, and yep, the user has the value of true:

[image: This is an image]

Yet the users background remains blank....

[image: This is an image]

However, the confusing part - when I click something else (which appears irrelevant, a different toggle to show and hide the whole panel) the user then gets the class applied.

[image: This is an image]
[image: This is an image]

What am I missing here? This seems strange, even for me!

Here is the full code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-sheet
            max-width="100%"
        >
            <v-card-title class="text-h7 grey-bg pt-0 pb-0">
                Line Managers
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-switch
                        class="mt-2"
                        :input-value="showLM"
                        @click="showLM = !showLM"
                    ></v-switch>

            </v-card-title>
        </v-sheet>
        <v-slide-y-transition>
            <v-sheet
                class="mx-auto"
                elevation="1"
                max-width="100%"
                v-show="showLM"
            >
                <div class="text-center pa-10" v-if="lineManagerLoading">
                    <v-progress-circular
                        :size="100"
                        :width="6"
                        color="primary"
                        indeterminate
                    ></v-progress-circular>
                </div>
                <v-slide-group
                    class="pa-2"
                    show-arrows
                    center-active
                    v-if="!lineManagerLoading"
                >
                    <v-slide-item
                        v-for="(member, i) in staff"
                        :key="member.id"
                    >
                        <v-card
                            class="text-center m-2"
                            :class="member.toggle ? 'primary' : 'grey lighten'"
                            width="100px"
                            @click="staffSelected(member)"
                        >
                            {{member.toggle}}
                            <v-avatar
                                color="#33304f"
                                size="94"
                                tile
                                class="profile-image m-1"
                                style="cursor:pointer;transition-duration:0.7s"
                                :style="member.toggle ? 'opacity:1.0' : 'opacity:0.5'"
                            >
                                <v-img
                                    :src="'/img/profile-pictures/'+member.profile_photo"
                                >
                                </v-img>
                            </v-avatar>
                            <v-spacer class="m-0 p-0"></v-spacer>
                            <div class="pb-1">
                                <small class="text-truncate d-block pl-1 pr-1" :style="member.toggle ? 'color:white' : 'grey'">
                                    {{member.first_name}}
                                </small>
                                <small class="text-truncate d-block pl-1 pr-1" :style="member.toggle ? 'color:white' : 'grey'">
                                    {{member.last_name}}
                                </small>
                            </div>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-slide-item>
                </v-slide-group>
            </v-sheet>
        </v-slide-y-transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapGetters} from "vuex";

    export default {
        components: {
        },
        data () {
            return {
                staff: [],
                lineManagerLoading: true,
                showLM: true,
            }
        },
        computed:{
            ...mapGetters({
                workingLineManaged: 'performanceManagement/getWorkingLineManaged',
                staffLoading: 'performanceManagement/getStaffLoading',
                authUser: 'global/getAuthUser'
            })
        },
        methods:{
            async staffSelected(member){
                member.toggle = true;
                await axios
                    .get('/app/performance-management/getLineManagedByUser?id=' + member.id)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.$store.commit('performanceManagement/updateWorkingLineManaged', response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                    .finally( () => this.$store.commit('performanceManagement/updateStaffLoading', false))
            },
            async populateLineManagers(){
                await axios
                    .get('/app/performance-management/getLineManagers')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.staff = response.data
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                    .finally(() => this.lineManagerLoading = false)
            },
        },
        watch: {
        },
        mounted(){
            this.populateLineManagers();
        },
        created(){
        }

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    ::v-deep .v-slide-group__content{
        justify-content:center;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to use Vue.set(member, 'toggle', true); Vue wasn't being notified about the change, but this did the trick!